# Windows Form Combo Box display & values out of sync

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

I have developed a small application but ran into this problem, so I'm starting with a clean slate to try and isolate it. So far, I made a very simple Windows form (VS 2017) application connecting to an SQL data table. On the form, I have a combo box for selecting a table row that is bound to the data set. I have it displaying an order number, and have its value member as an EntryID number as shown, which is also the "selected value".

[image: Combo Box Data Settings]

I also have a simple text box on the form displaying the EntryID.

When I run the app, the combo box initially displays an ordered list of order numbers like this:

[image]

Before selecting an item, if I scroll through the list using the form's tool bar selector, the EntryID text box value corresponds to the combo box value, so Ord40 selects the last data set row (where EntryID = 1003).

When an item is selected, however, the combo box list order changes. For example, after a few selections, I get:

[image]

But if I select the last display item, "Ord 20", I *still* get the data row EntryID = 1003. In other words, although the bound data set does not change, the combobox scrambles the displayed item. Put yet another way, if the combobox has a set of display fields and a corresponding set of value fields, the display field text get out of sync with the underlying value.
I hope that makes sense. This is straight, out of the box, no altered code on a fresh project, and I have tried different settings on the "selected value" property. 
Any help would be much appreciated.
James

Answer (score 2):

You are binding `SelectedValue` of the `ComboBox` to the same data source which you use as data source of the control. Setting `DataSource` is just for showing items in dropdown. Setting `SelecetdValue` if for changing the value of bound property/column.

You never want to bind `SelectedValue` to the same data source which you use for `DataSource`.

Just as a an example, assuming you have the following tables:

- `Product  (Id, Name, CategoryId, Price)`
- `Category (Id, Name)`

Then if you want to show a `ComboBox` for `CategoryId` in the edit form of `Product`, the setup of the `categoryIdComboBox` should be:

- `DataSource`: `categoriesDataSource`
- `DisplayMember`: `Name`
- `ValueMember`: `Id`
- `SelectedValue`: `productsBindigSource - CategoryId`

Comment: Thank you for your helpful response, which makes sense. I have the SelectedValue bound to a different data source now, the same data source as the text boxes on the form. The combobox stays ordered now, however, now the form no longer updates to the selection. How do I make the "selected value" data source synchronize with the ValueMember?

Comment: It should work properly if you use settings similar to what I shared as example in the answer. Make sure the `ValueMember` is set correctly. Trying to get your attention into the example in the answer, the `SelectedValue` should bind to `CategoryId` of `productsBindingSource`, the binding source which other text boxes are bound to. Also the `DataSource` of the combo box should be different, `categoriesBindingSource` to show categories while the `ValueMember` should set to `Id` of `categoriesBindingSource`.